# Heat equation with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I would like to explore some ideas with different geometries exchanging energy mainly by radiation.
This means solving Laplace equation for the steady state.
However the boundary conditions are always Neumann's because the only constraints are fluxes. After many questions and attempts, I realized that Mathematica cannot (yet ?) treat PDEs with Neumann boundary conditions.

To my great surprise I have also found no literature describing the treatment of the heat equation with the derivative at boundary proportional to $T^4$ even if I thought that similar problems would play a paramount role in engineering.

What are some good books/papers to treat the Heat equation with Neumann boundary conditions and more specifically when the flux at boundary is proportional to $T^4$ ?

Comment: Generally speaking Mathematica (version 9 at least, and probably (??) earlier) *should* be able to support Neumann boundary conditions. Try [tutorial/NDSolvePDE](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html) in the Mathematica documentation. If for some reason you have trouble making it work for you you should try the [Mathematica stackexchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).